# Why Do We Only Take Norms Over Real/Complex Numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

By definition, norms are defined over some $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ vector space. Why do we only restrict ourselves to these fields when other fields give rise to interesting objects as well? (e.g. p-adic evaluation)

Is it a historic reason or because other fields would give properties so different that we‘d rather not also associate the term “norm“ with it? If so, then I assume that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are similar enough to make those the two fields that give rise to norms?

Comment: As you can see, range of norm is $\mathbb{R}$. To compare things, we use this map, to $\mathbb{R}$, an *ordered* field.

Comment: You can more generally consider valued fields $K$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)#Dedekind_valuation and introduce the concept of a norm on vector spaces over $K$.

Comment: A difference I can think of now is the [open balls](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/open-and-closed-balls-in-metric-spaces) we get from Euclidean norm and that from $p$-adic norm.

Comment: @taritgoswami What about $\mathbb{Q}$? It‘s not too difficult to construct many other ordered fields. I‘m also not too sure the range of the norm gives an answer to my question. It is an interesting comment, nonetheless, though. Another (striking) difference would be that equivalence of norms wouldn‘t be true for all finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: The absolute values over $\mathbb{Q}$ have been completely classified by Ostrowski's Theorem---they're all equivalent to a $p$-adic valuation or the regular absolute value. We usually consider the base field to be complete wrt its absolute value so that the vector space is complete wrt its norm. Which means we're stuck with $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and their finite algebraic extensions. There is also $\mathbb{F}_p((x))$ that you could take as a base field. But at this point you've exhausted all complete base fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is true. People who work in $p$-adic analysis often work with with the quantity $|\vec{x}| = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} (|x_i|_p)$ for $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{Q}_p^n$, with $|\ |_p$ the $p$-adic norm. This is a norm in the sense that $|\vec{x}+\vec{y}| \leq \max(|\vec{x}|, |\vec{y}|)$, $|c \vec{x}| \leq |c|_p |\vec{x}|$ and $|\vec{x}|=0$ if and only if $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$. The metric induced by this norm on $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$ gives the standard product topology.

The group of matrices preserving this norm is a useful group: It is the matrices $g$ for which both $g$ and $g^{-1}$ have entries in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. It is usually denoted $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, and plays the analogue of the orthogonal group. Indeed, [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) for the PID $\mathbb{Z}_p$ says that every matrix in $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ can be factored as $U \Sigma V$ where $U$ and $V$ are in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and $\Sigma$ is diagonal with entries powers of $p$; it is valuable to think of this as a non-Archimedean analogue of [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

I learned this perspective from Chapter 4 of Kiran Kedlaya's book "[$p$-adic differential equations](https://kskedlaya.org/papers/p-adic_differential_equations.pdf)" and I have seen plenty of other $p$-adic papers use it since.

I just looked at the OP's bio, and it looks like they are a young undergraduate. So the reason they haven't seen this might just be that linear algebra books written for undergraduates don't assume the reader knows what the $p$-adics are.

Comment: It‘s a good comment, I especially liked the second part. However, I don‘t think I can quite agree completely. As mentioned, $p$-adics is the main motivation to consider other fields than $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ (though surely there are plently of other structures that can be defined on other fields), however, I‘ve never seen vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ to have a „norm“. See e.g. Wikipedia or any Linear Algebra/Functional Analysis/... book. As far as I‘ve seen, people like to give those „absolute values“ other names than norms. Perhaps I‘m wrong, though.

Comment: And yes, indeed, I‘ve currently just started my 2nd year at uni. Most 1st year undergraduates probably don‘t know about p-adics. But it‘s still easy to construct a function over $\mathbb{Q}$ vector spaces that possesses the same properties as a norm, right? Just take a norm and use rational scalars instead of real ones for instance.

Answer (score 6):

A norm on a space $V$ also induces a metric on $V$ (more or less by definition), and a metric is by definition a map from $V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. So, the norm should map the elements of $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and we require that $\left\|\alpha x\right\| = |\alpha| \left\|x\right\|$ for norm properties. So, $|\alpha|$ must also be a real number for any $\alpha$ in the field which $V$ is over. This pretty much limits the choice of field to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Of course, this answer pretty much just pushes the question to why we want metrics to map to $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: I agree that this limits the choice of the field. I‘m not sure about whether it immediately limits it to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, take for instance $\mathbb{Q}$ and observe the p-adic norm I‘ve mentioned. And your follow-up question is interesting as well!

Comment: Thinking about it more, perhaps the choice of $\mathbb{R}$ is because we want to take limits, and $\mathbb{R}$ is the only *complete* ordered field.

Comment: Hm possibly a reason, however, one also defines norms over $\mathbb{C}$ - it‘s either that or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: True, but in a sense $\mathbb{C}$ is complete as well... I'm not familiar with $p$-adic fields; can they be considered complete in any way?

Comment: Indeed but there are many complete fields, aren‘t there? I‘m not familiar with $p$-adics either but I do know that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ about the metric induced by the $p$-adic norm. However, the thing is that this norm is over $\mathbb{Q}$ and not $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: That relation only limits the field if you insist on the standard absolute value. There are ways to define a [real-valued absolute value on arbitrary fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29). There may be other reasons why it won't work on vector spaces on arbitrary fields, but this is not one.

Answer (score 6):

I think that if you want to work with norms on vector spaces over fields in general, then you have to use the concept of valuation.

**Valued field:**
Let $K$ be a field with valuation $|\cdot|:K\to\mathbb{R}$. This is, for all $x,y\in K$, $|\cdot|$ satisfies:

1. $|x|\geq0$,
2. $|x|=0$ iff $x=0$,
3. $|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$,
4. $|xy|=|x||y|$.

The set $|K|:=\{|x|:x\in K-\{0\}\}$ is a multiplicative subgroup of $(0,+\infty)$ called the value group of $|\cdot|$. The valuation is called *trivial*, *discrete* or *dense* accordingly as its value group is $\{1\}$, a discrete subset of $(0,+\infty)$ or a dense subset of $(0,+\infty)$. For example, the usual valuations in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are dense valuations.

**Norm:** Let $(K,|\cdot|)$ be a valued field and $X$ be a vector space over $(K,|\cdot|)$. A function $p:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a norm iff for each $a,b\in X$ and each $k\in K$, it satisfies:

1. $p(a)\geq0$ and $p(a)=0$ iff $a=0_X$,
2. $p(ka)=|k|p(a)$,
3. $p(a+b)\leq p(a)+p(b)$

There is a whole research area in which arbitrary valued fields are considered and these fields are not necessarily ordered fields. It is called non-Archimedean Functional Analysis. A comprehensive starting point to read about normed spaces in this context is the book: Non-Archimedean Functional Analysis - [A.C.M. van Rooij] - Dekker New York (1978).

For the study of more advanced stuff, like locally convex spaces over valued fields I recommend the book: Locally Convex Spaces over non-Arquimedean Valued Fields - [C.Perez-Garcia,W.H.Schikhof] - Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics (2010).

Now if you wonder whether the concept of valuation can be generalized, the answer is yes. On a field $K$ you can take a map $|\cdot|:K\mapsto G\cup\{0\}$ satisfying

1. $|x|\geq0$,
2. $|x|=0$ iff $x=0$,
3. $|x+y|\leq max\{|x|,|y|\}$,
4. $|xy|=|x||y|$.

where $G$ is an arbitrary multiplicative ordered group and $0$ is an element such that $0<g$ for all $g\in G$. In this new setting, a norm can take values in an ordered set $Y$ in which $G$ acts making of $Y$ a $G$-module. 
For an introdution in this area I recommend the paper:

[Banach spaces over fields with a infinite rank valuation, In J. Kakol, N. De Grande-De Kimpe, and C. Perez-Garcia, editors, p-adic Functional Analysis, volume 207 of Lecture Notes in Pure and Appl. Math., pages 233-293. Marcel Dekker - [H.Ochsenius A., W.H.Schikhof] - 1999](http://repository.ubn.ru.nl/bitstream/handle/2066/60088/60088.pdf)

After that see: [Norm Hilbert spaces over Krull valued fields - [H. Ochsenius, W.H. Schikhof] - Indagationes Mathematicae, Elsevier - 2006](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357706800078)